# Angular Material 1.0 rc4 Form Validation Example

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a few requirements for validating a form, and my attempts have been unsuccessful.

- The form should validate as you fill it out. The `md-input-container` should be invalid if the validation requirements fail and the associated ngMessage should show. For example, if an input is marked as `required` it should turn red and show the message if you click into it and then move focus without typing anything.
- The inputs should also be invalid if the form is submitted and they fail validation.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<md-input-container md-is-error="jac.application.$invalid && (jac.application.$submitted || jac.application.$dirty)" flex="20">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="jac.application_object.last_name" required />
  <div ng-messages="jac.application.last_name.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Using the above, submitting the form without entering anything has the desired effect; however, entering something valid into the input afterwards ONLY clears the ngMessage (the container is still red).

Also, the form doesn't validate as you fill it out.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have u opened an issue on the angular material repo?

Comment: This is probably broken, take into account that it's a beta and it still has a lot of bugs... Try with a previous build, sometimes features get broken for some days until they fix them.